# Domain of a function $f(x)= \sqrt{| x |} \cdot(2-\ln x^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-functions

Is the domain of the function $f(x)= \sqrt{|x|}\cdot(2-\ln x^2)$ the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ or $(0, \infty)$ ?

Comment: since $|x|\ge0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we do not need to worry about $\sqrt{x}$ being undefined. Similarly, $x^2\ge0$ and so the only point we need to worry about is where $x^2=0$ since $\log0$ does not exist. Hence the maximal domain ought to be $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: The function doesn't care whether you plug in a positive or a negative, the $|x|$ and $x^2$ parts take care of that. The only yelp you will get is when you try to find $\ln 0$.

Comment: Technically, you could also declare $D:=(0,9001)$ to be the domain. You ask for the biggest domain $D \subset \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is $\{x \in \mathcal{D}(f) \mid f(x) \geq 0\}$, where $\mathcal{D}(f)$ is the domain of $f$.

The domain of $\ln g(x)$ is $\{x \in \mathcal{D}(g) \mid g(x) > 0\}$.

Furthermore, the domain of a product of functions is the intersection of the domains of the individual functions. That is $\mathcal{D}(pq) = \mathcal{D}(p)\cap\mathcal{D}(q)$.

So, what do you think?

Comment: I think it's $x \in(0, \infty)$

Comment: Why? How did you use the information I provided to deduce that?

Comment: Because $g(x)=lnx^2$ and $lnx^2=2 \cdot lnx$. Domain for $lnx$ is $x>0$ and $f(x)>=0$ so their cross-section is $x>0$

Comment: $g(x)$ is the function inside of the natural logarithm. Note that $\ln x^n = n\ln x$ only for $x > 0$; the expression on the left side may be defined for $x < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no problems when $x<0$, (both $\ln{x^2}$ and $\sqrt{|x|}$ are well defined functions), it would be the former.